# Master Detail Relationship question

Tags: master-detail, sharing-rule

i have master-detail relationship between A&B object where A is master and B is child. Now when a record is created in object B by a user, it is visible by other user also. Is their any way to stop the visibility of a user record to other user.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup / Sharing Settings / find your child object, and set its default visibility to "private" .

Comment: Child object is controlled by parent therefore  am not able to set to private

Answer (score 0):

Visibility is usually managed by sharings. If you set the sharing of the Master object to private in Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults, only the owner of the record and people in roles above could see the record. There are plenty of ways to configure visibility.

Comment: If we set set the visibility of master to private then users will not be able to see master object records. Actually records in master object is created by admin. users should not touch master object records(but they need to see) whereas they need to work only on child object. since one field is master detail in child object, all users can each other record(need to stop this).